# Вопрос о @media в css

Tags: css

Я только начал изучать @media, что у меня есть:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) {}
```

Но, мне нужно туда еще впихнуть `max-widht: 1700px`, но моя IDLE не дает этого сделать, погуглил - ответа нету. Может у кого есть другой способ, и я чего-то не понимаю? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-width:1700px) {
  .root {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Всё отрабатывает